# Avoid refreshing of content in SplitLayout

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

I have a splitlayout in my vaadin application in which in the first column I should show different pages added through the addToPrimary method, while in the second column I should have a page which contains an IFrame with a videoconference. Now the problem is that when I change route in the first column, even the second is updated and this refreshes the IFrame.  The implementation of the showRouterLayoyutContent is the following:

```
    @Override
public void showRouterLayoutContent(HasElement content) {

    if (this.accessControl.isAccessGranted(UI.getCurrent(), ((ContentView) content).getName()) && ((ContentView) content).getName().equals("contattaView") ) {
        setLayoutCall((com.vaadin.flow.component.Component) content);
    }
    else if (this.accessControl.isAccessGranted(UI.getCurrent(), ((ContentView) content).getName())) {
        setLayoutContent((com.vaadin.flow.component.Component) content);

    }

}
```

And the two methods setLayoutCall and setLayoutContent are the following:

```
private void setLayoutContent(com.vaadin.flow.component.Component content) {

    split.addToPrimary(content);

}
private void setLayoutCall(com.vaadin.flow.component.Component content) {

    split.addToSecondary(content);
    split.setThemeName("visible-split");
}
```

How can I avoid to refresh the entire content when I update the first column of the split layout through navigation?

---

**UPDATE:** I'm showing also a very simple code on which I'm testing. The following class is the main layout:

```
private SplitLayout split = new SplitLayout();
    private HorizontalLayout hl = new HorizontalLayout();
    private Div firstDiv = new Div();
    private Div secondDiv = new Div();
    public MainView() {
        Button button = new Button("Click me",
                event -> Notification.show("Clicked!"));
        final VerticalLayout menuBar = new VerticalLayout();
        menuBar.add(new RouterLink("first view", FirstView.class));
        menuBar.add(new RouterLink("second view", SecondView.class));
        menuBar.setAlignItems(Alignment.CENTER);
        add(menuBar);
        //split.addToPrimary(firstDiv);
        //split.addToSecondary(secondDiv);
        //firstDiv.setId("first");
        //secondDiv.setId("second");
        //hl.add(firstDiv,secondDiv);
        add(split);
        //add(hl);
    }

    @Override
    public void showRouterLayoutContent(HasElement element) {

        if(element!=null && element.getClass().getName().contains("FirstView")) {
            split.addToPrimary((Component) element);
            //firstDiv.removeAll();
            //firstDiv.add((Component) element);
            //firstDiv.removeAll();      
            //firstDiv.getElement().appendChild(new Element[]{element.getElement()});

        }
        else if(element!=null && element.getClass().getName().contains("SecondView") ) {
            secondDiv.removeAll();
            secondDiv.add((Component) element);
            split.addToSecondary((Component) element);
            //split.addToSecondary(element.getElement().getComponent().get());
        }


    }
```

While these are the two views added to the split:

```
    @Route(value="v1",layout=MainView.class)
public class FirstView extends VerticalLayout implements RouterLayout  {

    public FirstView() {
        add(new Label("First View"));
    }
}
```

```
@Route(value = "v2",layout=MainView.class)
public class SecondView extends VerticalLayout implements RouterLayout {
public SecondView() {
    IFrame frame = new IFrame();
    frame.setSrc("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LoigVtPCYPk&list=RDLoigVtPCYPk&start_radio=1");
    add(frame);
}
}
```

Comment: How are your routes constructed, and how do you navigate between them?

Comment: I Just use a  vertical menu in which routes are defined through RouterLink

Comment: Do you navigate twice to get the two parts to show? Or do you call showRouterLayoutContent manually?

And does the iframe completely disappear, or does it just refresh?

Comment: yes i navigate 2 times to see both pages in split layout. No I don't call showRouterLayoutContent manually, it's called automatically when a link in the menu is clicked. I saw the implementation of SplitLayout, in particular for the method setComponents which removes all child elements before readding them. I think it's the principal cause that causes Iframe to refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Your comment does indeed seem to be the issue.

I recommend creating a `Div` wrapper for the primary content, and instead changing the content of that.

```
private final Div wrapper;

public MyLayout() {
    wrapper = new Div();
    wrapper.setSizeFull();

    split.addToPrimary(wrapper);
}

private void setLayoutContent(com.vaadin.flow.component.Component content) {
    wrapper.removeAll();
    wrapper.add(content);
}
```

You might also want to do the same for the secondary. In addition, to prevent any components from being automatically removed when navigating, you can override `removeRouterLayoutContent` as well (available in Vaadin 14)

```
@Override
public void removeRouterLayoutContent(HasElement oldContent) {
    // Do nothing, we remove manually in showRouterLayoutContent
}
```

**Edit**

If you can't override `removeRouterLayoutContent`, you can try creating your own instance of the `HasElement` to add. This is a bit of a hack, but might be the simplest solution.

```
public void showRouterLayoutContent(HasElement content) {
    if (content.getClass().getSimpleName().contains("TestView")) {
        // Creating a new instance should stop it from being auto removed 
        content = new TestView();
        firstDiv.add((Component) content);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Well, with divs added to split, now if i add to primary the div in the secondary disappers, while if I add to secondary it's the primary to disappear. _removeRouterLayoutContent_ also is not defined in RouterLayout interface. I'm using Vaadin 13

Comment: Right, seems that the method is not available before V14, which is in beta and will be released next week.

When navigating between routes with the same parent layout, Vaadin automatically removes the old content before adding the new one, which is why you're seeing what you're seeing.

Initially it worked (with the refresh), because SplitLayout#setComponents re-added the component that the Router removed.

To avoid refresh, you need to stop the Router from removing the old content, in addition to using the Div "hack". If you can't wait for V14 it will be tricky.

Comment: One workaround is to create your own instance of the videoconference view, and add that instead. Vaadin will only try to remove the instance that was passed to the `showRouterLayoutContent` method.

Comment: Unfortunatelly  I can't wait for V 14. Could you give me an example? If I have a view class called ContactView, how can I pass this instance to split layout instead of using showrouterlayout?